# bn.inherits is not a function in snarkjs

Tags: blockchain, evm, rollups, circom

i am going through this https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs to make zk-rollup via .circom and snarkJS, when i tried to run index.html code it didn't work as per it should. and give error  `bn.inherits is not a function`. HTML code:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Snarkjs client example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Snarkjs client example</h1>
  <button id="bGenProof"> Create proof </button>

  <!-- JS-generated output will be added here. -->
  <pre class="proof"> Proof: <code id="proof"></code></pre>

  <pre class="proof"> Result: <code id="result"></code></pre>

  <script src="snarkjs.min.js"></script>


  <!-- This is the bundle generated by rollup.js -->
  <script>

const proofComponent = document.getElementById('proof');
const resultComponent = document.getElementById('result');
const bGenProof = document.getElementById("bGenProof");

bGenProof.addEventListener("click", calculateProof);

async function calculateProof() {

    const { proof, publicSignals } =
      await snarkjs.groth16.fullProve({"a":"123","b":"234"}, "product.wasm", "product_0000.zkey");

    proofComponent.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(proof, null, 1);


    const vkey = await fetch("verification_key.json").then( function(res) {
        return res.json();
    });

    const res = await snarkjs.groth16.verify(vkey, publicSignals, proof);

    resultComponent.innerHTML = res;
}

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error using the latest `snarkjs.min.js` from github/iden3

I had an older file from early 2023 and it works find with no error. I suggest downloading a file from the git history.